# How to find the changed value in history table sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find out if the PAYMENT METHOD has been changed for a particular ID from the last time he pays.

| ID | PAYMENT METHOD | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CASH | 2022 |
| 1 | VISA | 2021 |
| 1 | CASH | 2020 |
| 2 | CASH | 2021 |
| 2 | CASH | 2020 |
| 2 | CASH | 2019 |
| 3 | CHEQUE | 2021 |
| 3 | VISA | 2020 |
| 3 | VISA | 2019 |
| 4 | CASH | 2021 |
| 4 | CASH | 2020 |
| 4 | CASH | 2019 |

For example, ID 1 and ID 3 changed their payment method and I want to write a query that can detect that change, thanks in advance

example for expected outputs (I want to have a table that contains the changed payment method):

| ID | PAYMENT METHOD HAS CHANGED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CASH |
| 3 | CHEQUE |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` and `count()` analytic functions:

```
with u as
(select ID,
"PAYMENT METHOD",
row_number() over(partition by ID order by "DATE" desc) as rn,
count(distinct "PAYMENT METHOD") over(partition by ID) as cnt
from table_name)
select ID, "PAYMENT METHOD" from u
where rn = 1 and cnt >= 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need simple aggregation with `having` clause: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0e8ac76cf42bb0cc3ddb8190c6f58e7d)

```
select
   id, 
   max(payment_method)
     keep(dense_rank last order by dt) as LAST_PAYMENT_METHOD
from t
group by id
having count(distinct payment_method)>1;
```

Full example with test data:

```
with t(ID, PAYMENT_METHOD, DT) as (
select 1, 'CASH'  , to_date(2022,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 1, 'VISA'  , to_date(2021,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 1, 'CASH'  , to_date(2020,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 2, 'CASH'  , to_date(2021,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 2, 'CASH'  , to_date(2020,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 2, 'CASH'  , to_date(2019,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 3, 'CHEQUE', to_date(2021,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 3, 'VISA'  , to_date(2020,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 3, 'VISA'  , to_date(2019,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 4, 'CASH'  , to_date(2021,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 4, 'CASH'  , to_date(2020,'YYYY') from dual union all
select 4, 'CASH'  , to_date(2019,'YYYY') from dual
)
select
   id, 
   max(payment_method)
     keep(dense_rank last order by dt) as LAST_PAYMENT_METHOD
from t
group by id
having count(distinct payment_method)>1;
```

Output:

```
        ID LAST_PAYMENT_METHOD
---------- --------------------
         1 CASH
         3 CHEQUE
```